# Using REGEXP_LIKE in Oracle

Tags: oracle, regexp-like

In the MyTable table, I have the following data in the MyField column whose size is 80 characters:

```
MyField
-------
WA
W
W51534
W
W
```

I am trying to exclude lines starting with WA through regexp_like. But the following query returns the W51534 line and not the W lines :

```
select MyField
    from MyTable
    where regexp_like (upper (ltrim (MyField)), '^ [W][^A]');
```

I would like it to also return lines W. How can I do?

thank you in advance

Comment: Edit your question and show us the real problem.

Comment: What if MyField is NULL?

Answer (score 0):

You may not even need to use `REGEXP_LIKE` here, regular `LIKE` may suffice:

```
SELECT MyField
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyField NOT LIKE 'WA%';
```

### Demo

Comment: Yes I know. But it is important for me to do it in regex_like because there are different cases similar to different places. But I don't know why ^[W][[:space:]] don't also works.Thinks

Comment: the problem is the spaces. When I use rpad, it works. it's not convenient, but it works.
regexp_like (upper(rpad(MyField,80,'#')), '^[W][^A]')

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved my problem, as I said in comment, by adding the rpad command :
regexp_like (upper(rpad(MyField,80,'#')), '^[W][^A]');
If someone has a better idea, I'm interested.
thinks

Answer (score 0):

You can negate the regexp_like, so have it match the patterns you don't want:

```
with mytable(id, myfield) as (
  select 1, 'WA' from dual union all
  select 2, 'W' from dual union all
  select 3, 'W51534' from dual union all
  select 4, 'Z' from dual union all
  select 5, '' from dual
)
select id, myfield
from mytable
where not regexp_like(upper(myfield), '^WA') or 
myfield is null
order by id;
```